# Finding all missing numbers in a list

Tags: python

I'm trying to find the missing number in a list. Assume list is always sorted. I tried to loop over the list and compared if element in the list has the position of where `i` is at. If not then append the element to a separate list of `missing_array = []`

```py
def missing_number(myArray):
    
    missingArray = []
    length = len(myArray) + 1
    
    for i in range(1, length):
        
        print(i)
        
        if i not in myArray:
            missingArray.append(i)
    
    return missingArray

case = [1, 5, 7, 8]
print(missing_number(case))
```

The output should be `[2,3,4,6]` but I only got `[2,3,4]`;

Comment: Apparently you assumed that the greatest number in the input array is `length`, but the example case does not hold to that rule. Did you misinterpret the code challenge or did you experiment with invalid inputs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you're only looking for numbers from 1 to 4, because you're only looking for the *length*. What you need to be looking for is numbers between the minimum and maximum values in the list instead; I'd change the line:

```
for i in range(1, length):
```

to:

```
for i in range(min(myArray)+1, max(myArray)):
```

(I use `min` plus 1 and `max` as the bounds because you obviously don't actually need to check the end values to see if they're missing: the ends are already in there, or else they wouldn't be the end values)

Comment: it can be even reduced to a oneliner: `[i for i in range(min(arr)+1,max(arr)) if i not in arr]`

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by finding the symmetric difference between two sets as follows:

```
def missing_number(myList): # myList is assumed to be sorted ascending
    return sorted(set(myList).symmetric_difference(range(myList[0], myList[-1]+1)))

print(missing_number([1, 5, 7, 8]))
```

**Output:**

```
[2, 3, 4, 6]
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of running the loop for `range(1,length)`, you should loop through all values from 1 to myArray[-1], that is set the loop range to `range(1, myArray[-1]+1)`.

```py
def missing_number(myArray):
    
    missingArray = []
    range_limit = myArray[-1] + 1
    
    for i in range(1, range_limit):
        
        print(i)
        
        if i not in myArray:
            missingArray.append(i)
    
    return missingArray

case = [1, 5, 7, 8]
print(missing_number(case))
```

would print `[2,3,4,6]` as expected

Answer (score 1):

Since you can assume that the original list is sorted, you can blindly append all numbers in `range(lst[i]+1, lst[i+1])` to your `missing_numbers` list:

```
def missing_number(lst):
    missing_numbers = []
    for i in range(len(lst)-1):
        missing_numbers.extend(range(lst[i]+1, lst[i+1]))

    return missing_numbers
```

`range(lst[i]+1, lst[i+1])` contains all integers after the `i`th element of `lst` up to (but not including) the `i+1`th element of `lst`. Following the iterations on paper, we can see:

| iteration (`i`) | `lst[i]` | `lst[i+1]` | numbers added to `missing_numbers` (`range(...)`) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 5 | 2, 3, 4 |
| 1 | 5 | 7 | 6 |
| 2 | 7 | 8 | - |

Now, `missing_number([1, 5, 7, 8])` gives `[2, 3, 4, 6]` as expected.

Comment: That's a smart one ;)

Answer (score 1):

As other answer already explained the issue with your solution, I'll rather comment on the complexity. As you are using `if i not in myArray`, you check against the whole list for each `i`, which has quadratic complexity.

You could use a `set` to avoid that, but trying to use your initial logic, let's modify the way we iterate over the list to use two pointers, one to keep track of the number to test (`n`), and one for the position (`pos`):

```
def missing_number(myArray):
    n = 1
    pos = 0
    out = []
    while pos < len(myArray) and n <= myArray[-1]:
        if n == myArray[pos]:
            pos += 1
        else:
            out.append(n)
        n += 1
    return out

missing_number([1, 5, 7, 8])
# [2, 3, 4, 6]

missing_number([])
# []

missing_number([1, 2, 3])
# []

missing_number([2, 3, 10])
# [1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Intermediates for each iteration:

```
n  pos  out
1   0   []
2   1   []
3   1   [2]
4   1   [2, 3]
5   1   [2, 3, 4]
6   2   [2, 3, 4]
7   2   [2, 3, 4, 6]
8   3   [2, 3, 4, 6]
```

Answer (score 1):

Given that your numbers are in increasing order, you can use each consecutive pair as a range and output the values in between.  Using zip allows you to get each pair of start/end for the ranges and a nested comprehension will give the result directly:

```
case   = [1, 5, 7, 8]
result = [m for s,e in zip(case,case[1:]) for m in range(s+1,e)]

print(result) # [2, 3, 4, 6]
```

If you are not comfortable with zip and comprehensions, you can use a more procedural approach by tracking the previous value as you go through the second and subsequent items.  Uses previous and current as the range and extend the result as you go:

```
case   = [1, 5, 7, 8]

result = []
start  = case[0]
for end in case[1:]:
    result.extend(range(start+1,end))
    start = end

print(result) # [2, 3, 4, 6]
```